# native SSRS scaleout solution in Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, reporting-services, azure-sql-database, azure-load-balancer

I would like to know if there is a native SSRS scale-out solution without having domain services in Azure.

I have tried to run it with Azure load balancer and Azure VM's but it doesn't work without having a domain user.

Answer (score 0):

Going through the docs I see, [Configure a Native Mode Report Server Scale-Out Deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/configure-a-native-mode-report-server-scale-out-deployment?view=sql-server-ver15) where you can follow steps [To plan, install, and configure a scale-out deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/configure-a-native-mode-report-server-scale-out-deployment?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=To%20plan%2C%20install%2C%20and%20configure%20a%20scale%2Dout%20deployment%2C%20follow%20these%20steps%3A).

Further, you can check out this private article by Paul Stanton: [Scaling SSRS Support for SQL Azure with Containers](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/scaling-ssrs-support-for-sql-azure-with-containers)